# XCode , can i search all views in xib files with a specific hex color?

Tags: xcode, xcode7

I'm working on an Ios app and i need to replace all the backgrounds color of my xib view from one code color to another, something like "replace #000000 with #666666".
Can i do this search with Xcode? I think that is impossible but maybe there's a way...

EDIT

This is what i can find in a xib opened as source code:

```
<color key="backgroundColor" red="0.1764705882" green="0.1529411765" blue="0.1333333333" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
```

But i can't search colors anyway

Comment: Are you sure the colours are defined using RGB?

Comment: from one of the latest xcode version, color can be defined with hex code also... But it's the same if i can search an rgb in my xibs

Comment: But are you sure that RGB has been used to define the colours within the `.xib` files?  Why not open them up in a text editor and see?  I don't know if they are or not, however I would expect not.

Comment: I have the same issue: I created a custom color in my custom colors palette, and after I assigned the color I noticed that the xib file doesn't contain the custom color's name (ie. pointer to that color), neither the hex code, but the values defined as in your post. Did you manage to find a solution for this?