# How to search hex colors used in Xib files in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, xib

How can I search all my xib or storyboard files for every place I used a hex color saved in my color palette? Xcode doesn't help me with that, it finds only references in code for that hex color.

If I open a xib as source code, what Xcode does is to keep only pointers to that custom color as rgb value like following:

```
<color key="backgroundColor" red="X" green="Y" blue="Z" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
```

This other post on stack describes the same issue:
[XCode , can i search all views in xib files with a specific hex color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34412555/xcode-can-i-search-all-views-in-xib-files-with-a-specific-hex-color#comment99137890_34412555)

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?